# correct way to create a button for html

Tags: html

Why there are different approach to create a button, and which one to use when.

```
<form>
<input type="button">
<button type="button"></button>
</form>
```

I would like to have some explanation.

Comment: With a <button> tag you can put more than just text in the button value, whilst input type="button" you're limited to your value="" field. For example, you can put icons inside your button tags.

Answer (score 1):

There are several difference but from you code the most relevant  is

`<input type="button">` as an input field is submited  when the form is sended  to  the server for elab and you could eval serverside the content of value attribute assigne to the input nutton

`<button type="button"></button>`  is only a client local tag